# One of my threads seems to exit earlier than I expected in my consumer/producer code

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, while-loop, thread-safety

So I am trying to make a simple producer/consumer code in java. My producer seems to work just fine however it reaches a point where it produces 10 items and then just stops producing items. Then I have to wait for the consumer to remove the 10 items added to the array List and I am left with the consumer having nothing left to consume since the producer doesn't add to the list.

I initially thought that for some reason the code seems to be breaking out of the while loop in my producer class but it could never do that so I'm honestly lost. Here is my code

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {


    public static boolean eating = true;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> buffet = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        //make our producer
        Thread producerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                producer();
                System.out.println("BUFFET IS CLOSED, NO MORE FOOD TO MAKE");
            }
        });

        //make our consumer
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                consumer();
            }
        });

        producerThread.start();
        consumerThread.start();

        consumerThread.join();
        producerThread.join();


    }

        private static void producer(){

            Random randomCooking = new Random();

            while(true){
                if(buffet.size() < 10) {
                    System.out.println("Producer added a dish");
                    buffet.add(randomCooking.nextInt(5));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }




        }

        private static void consumer() {

            Random randomEating = new Random();

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);

                    if (randomEating.nextInt(5) == 0) {

                        if(buffet.size() > 0) {

                            Integer value = buffet.remove(buffet.size() - 1);

                            switch (value) {
                                case 0:
                                    System.out.println("Dish 0: Shrimp & Rice, eaten by consumer! Dishes left: " + buffet.size());
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    System.out.println("Dish 1: Mashed Potatoes and Gravey, eaten by consumer! Dishes left: " + buffet.size());
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    System.out.println("Dish 2: Spaghetti and Meatballs, eaten by consumer! Dishes left: " + buffet.size());
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    System.out.println("Dish 3: Burger & Fries, eaten by consumer! Dishes left: " + buffet.size());
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    System.out.println("Dish 4: Salad & Tofu, eaten by consumer! Dishes left: " + buffet.size());
                                    break;

                            }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Food is all finished");

                        }

                    }else{
                        System.out.println("consumer decided not to eat! Dishes left: " + buffet.size() );
                    }

                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

After a while this is all I am left with

```
consumer decided not to eat! Dishes left: 0
consumer decided not to eat! Dishes left: 0
consumer decided not to eat! Dishes left: 0
consumer decided not to eat! Dishes left: 0
Food is all finished
consumer decided not to eat! Dishes left: 0
consumer decided not to eat! Dishes left: 0
```

Comment: You're modifying an ArrayList, which is not thread-safe, from two concurrent threads, and without any kind of synchronization. That can't possibly work in a correct way. Multi-threading is a complex matter. You need to study it, seriously.

Comment: Yes, I just figured out about the synchronized(this){ } call that I can make so I am just figuring out how to use that.  But even using that call my code still only adds 10 items and then stops adding items after they are consumed.

Comment: For one thing, when your producer hits 10 items, it goes into a busy-loop consuming 100% on one CPU. And it probably won't see any updates the the list length because you haven't used proper concurrency techniques, so it will remain in a busy-loop for a long while, possibly forever.

Comment: Ohhh ok that makes perfect sense. That's why it never actually finishes the run function it is just in a busy-loop for that whole time after producing 10 items!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList` is not suited for concurrent access.  It means if a thread modifies it and multiple threads access it concurrently, it must be synchronized externally. The simplest you can do - wrap it in [synchronized counterpart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) and synchronize access to it:

```
List<Integer> buffet = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
...
while (true) {
    synchronized (buffet) {
        // perform your operations
    }
}
```

Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior - as explicitly mentioned in the documentation (and, basically, what you are observing).

However, typically, the most useful data-structure for producer-consumer problems is [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). So you can use some of its implementations, e.g. [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) or [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).